# MissingKeyMapError when configuring Google Maps API

Tags: api, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, key

I am trying to configure the Google Maps API key on my website like this:

```html
<div class="rd-google-map">
  <div class="border-bottom"></div>
  <div id="google-map" class="rd-google-map__model" data-zoom="10" data-x="77.079627" data-y="28.643150"></div>
  <ul class="rd-google-map__locations">
    <li data-x="77.079627" data-y="28.643150">
      <p>58, Ist Floor, DDA Local Shopping Centre, Block J, Vikaspuri, Delhi, 110018</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

> "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error
>    http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js:34"

The URl is `dranandspetsclinic.com/new/`.

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: <div class="rd-google-map">
<div class="border-bottom"></div>
<div id="google-map" class="rd-google-map__model" data-zoom="10" data-x="77.079627" data-y="28.643150"></div>
                    <ul class="rd-google-map__locations">
                        <li data-x="77.079627" data-y="28.643150">
                            <p>
                                 58, Ist Floor, DDA Local Shopping Centre, Block J, Vikaspuri, Delhi, 110018
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

Comment: No one can read this. Edit your question and post it there in code-tags.

Comment: I've moved your comment with the code into the question and edited it a bit.

Comment: That error means that you need to add an API key to your request. Can you please include the code for your API request? I can probably help you out once I see the actual request.

Answer (score 1):

Open **js/script.js** and search for a line with something like this

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&v=3.7&key=ADD_YOUR_KEY_HERE", function ()
```

and add the &key=your_key_here from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?refresh=1