# how to include googe maps api key in rd google map plugin

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-api, api-key

i am using RD Google Map plugin but i can't find the google api script

the page do not display the map and display this error and a gray area instead of map

> js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&v=3.7&_=1525804623037:40 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error

[image]

then i tried to add this script line to initialize the google maps

```
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but this time the map did not display at all

with this error

> js?sensor=false&libr…&_=1525804236821:96 You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

[image]

if i include the script it says it is included multiple times and if i exclude it it says no key

please advice

thanks in advance

Comment: As the error message says, your HTML likely has multiple JS API script loads. You need to find all of the places where `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?`, remove all but one, and include your API key on the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching and digging i found the answer here

[MissingKeyMapError when configuring Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566791/missingkeymaperror-when-configuring-google-maps-api#48460817)

i tried the solution and find it helpful and the issue is solved